# Making \cdots compact when between terms with powers

Tags: typography

I am typesetting the following:

[image: Equation]

```
${z_1}^{a_{11}}\cdots{z_n}^{a_{n1}}, \dots, {z_1}^{a_{1k}}\cdots{z_n}^{a_{nk}}$
```

However, I would like it so that the \cdots are as close together as possible. Pretty much it would be great to have the dots start as close to the index of the first power, and then be as close together as possible, to make each term in the vector as compact as possible.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this (second line)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

${z_1}^{a_{11}}\cdots{z_n}^{a_{n1}}, \dots, {z_1}^{a_{1k}}\cdots{z_n}^{a_{nk}}$\\

$ z_1^{a_{11}}\mkern-2mu{\cdots }z_n^{a_{n1}}, \dots, z_1^{a_{1k}}\mkern-2mu{\cdots} z_n^{a_{nk}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep that's great - thanks!